# Computing transition function problem

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I'm studying vector bundles and I know that is a particular point of view in this subject, namely working with transition function. My problem is that I don't know how to compute transition function say for $E\otimes F$ where $E$ and $F$ are vector bundles over $M.$ My feeling sais that is not a complicated computation but I'm kinda new to the subject.

Comment: If you have automorphisms of two vectors spaces $V$ and $W$ how could you create an automorphism of $V \otimes W$ ?

Comment: I know what is the tensor product of two matrix so I'm guessing that the matrix associated to an automorphisms of $V\otimes W$ is a tenor product of matrix associated to auto automorphismes of $V$ and $W$ resp.

Comment: Yes, and in fact this is how you _define_ $E \otimes F$, since just saying what are the fibers is not enough to determine a vector bundle :-)

Comment: Yes but this dosen't help me to compute transition function in the future

Comment: Of course it does, just take the tensor product of the two transitions functions.

Comment: I understood that but the tensor product is just an example. Take another example like $\text{Lin}(E,F)$, $E\oplus F$ or $E^*$

Comment: For $E^*$ take the dual $f^*$, for $E \oplus F$ take the direct sum $f \oplus g$, and $Lin(E,F) \cong E^* \otimes F$ so you also know. Same for symetric product, and exterior products ...
In fact all what I wrote are the definitions of these objects, because again a vector bundle is characterized by its transition functions.
How would you define these vector bundles without knowing the transition functions ? :)